# Makefile produces different results when run second time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a rule like this in a makefile:

```
target : dependencies
   rm -rd somedirectory
   runcodecoverage.exe # this generates somefile
   $(eval COVERAGE=$(shell grep "blah" somefile))
   @echo $(COVERAGE)
```

When I run this file the first time (after make cleaning) the echo doesn't print anything. But the second and times after that, it prints the correct result. If I replace the $(eval ..) line with just `grep "blah" somefile` I get the result I want, so the problem must be in the use of $(eval) and $(shell). Why is this happening?

Edit: I solved this by adding a new dependency, so it now looks like this:

```
generatesomefile : 
   runcodecoverage.exe # this generates somefile

target : dependencies generatesomefile
   rm -rd somedirectory
   $(eval COVERAGE=$(shell grep "blah" somefile))
   @echo $(COVERAGE)
```

It seems like $(eval) was being substituted with the result of grep as soon as the "target" target was entered, even though I wanted it to be run after runcodecoverage.exe had run. In this sense the answer I accepted as correct wasn't quite right - the docs say this on variable expansion:

Rule Definition

A rule is always expanded the same way, regardless of the form:

immediate : immediate ; deferred
        deferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `eval` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) doesn't work the way you think it does.

The first time you run Make, it expands the `eval` function and carries out the variable assignment *before executing any rule.* And since there is no `somefile`, the `grep` returns nothing and `COVERAGE` stays empty. When Make executes the rule, it passes the empty variable to the `echo` which duly reports nothing.

The second time you run Make, once again it expands the `eval` function, executes the `grep` on `somefile` (which was built in the first run), and stores the result in `COVERAGE`. Then it executes the rule and passes `COVERAGE` to the `echo`, which puts it up on your screen.

Comment: Ahh. I need to stop thinking of make as a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(eval ...)` runs when your Makefile is parsed, not when the recipe is executed.

It's not clear to me what you expect to happen; setting a Make variable from within a recipe does not seem like a sustainable approach, but it depends a lot on where and how you need to use this variable.  If all you need is to output the coverage from the same recipe, replace the last couple of lines with just

```
grep "blah" somefile
```